# React Native: Scroll to input focus on iOS does not work properly

Tags: react-native

I would like have a behaviour such that when the input is focused, it is automatically scrolled to this input and the user cannot scroll himself.

On Android, I can use ScrollView to automatically scroll to input focus:

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} **scrollEnabled={false}**>
  {props.children}
</ScrollView>
```

However, this does not work on iOS. There is a library KeyboardAwareScrollView, which enables scroll to focused input field and the implementation looks like this:

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
  {props.children}
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

However, if I use scrollEnabled={false} property, then automatic scroll to input focus stops working. So to allow automatic scroll, I also have to allow manual scroll.

Is there a way to scroll to input focus without enabling user to scroll himself on iOS? KeyboardAvoidingView is not a solution to my case, as it does not scroll, but adds height/padding.